# c# toString() performance

Tags: c#, .net, tostring

I'm curious about the `ToString()` method in C#. Take for example the following:

```
object height = 10;

string heightStr = height.ToString();
```

When I call  `ToString()` on `height`, I get a string type back. Is the runtime allocating memory for this string?

Comment: ToString() is for humans, perf is a non-issue since they don't read that fast.  Should be anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the runtime is going to allocate memory for any string object that you create or request, including one that is returned from a method call.

But no, this is absolutely *not* something that you have to worry about. It will not have *any* noticeable effect on the performance of your application, and you should never give in to the temptation to optimize code prematurely.

The `Int32.ToString` method is extremely quick. It calls down to native code written at the level of the CLR, which is not likely to be a performance bottleneck in *any* application.

In fact, the *real* performance problem here is going to be [**boxing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), which is the process of converting a value type to type `object` and back again. This will occur because you declared the `height` variable as type `object`, and then assigned an integer value to it.

It is a far better idea to declare `height` explicitly as type `int`, like so:

```
int height = 10;
string heightStr = height.ToString();
```

Comment: One set of boxing/unboxing is not any more inefficient than allocating a string.

Comment: @Matti: No, one set might not be. I'd have to see performance data to be sure, but it's quite irrelevant here. The distinction that I was attempting to make is that boxing is something worth generally avoiding. It's considered a "bad practice" when writing .NET code, and it's certainly something for everyone to be aware of. String allocation is not a problem, nor is it something to avoid. There is a much greater potential for repeated boxing/unboxing operations to cause a performance problem in an app.

Comment: As a small note : boxing *also* occurs if you call a virtual method (such as ToString()) on a value-type variable/expression that **doesn't explicitly override it**. In the case of `int`, there *is* an explicit int.ToString(), but that isn't always the case.

Comment: Re "for any string object that you create or request" there is also the issue of interning, of course - doesn't apply here, but "any" is a big statement

Comment: I have to disagree with the opening statement.  There are situations where this would be a performance issue.  If this were to happen in a tight loop many times over, the cumulative effect of the allocations could cause an expensive garbage collection.  In a game garbage collections are very noticeable.  In a single generation collector like the one in the compact framework you also risk fragmentation, causing even more work for the collector.

Comment: Any application is a broad spectrum and it's not true also  applications that are based on constant fast speed it's important to not have allocations, an example for that are realtime media and voip applications

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Creating a new instance of a class (as is being done with the string class in this case) will allocate memory for the instance.

Comment: I'm not really sure how the fact that strings are immutable is relevant here. He's not modifying an existing instance of the `String` class, but rather assigning the result of the `ToString` function to a variable typed as a `string`. That's going to create a new instance of the class even if it *weren't* immutable.

Comment: @Cody I mentioned it to highlight the fact that all string instances are allocated a new memory address. You're right, its not highly relevant, but I thought that it might bring some additional clarity.  In any case, I've removed the mention of immutability to avoid confusion.