# Does a call to ToString() on a boolean always allocate memory

Tags: c#, .net, mono, clr, string-interning

Consider the following code:

```
private bool flag;

private void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine(flag.ToString());
}
```

Suppose that Test() is called multiple times, will it allocate memory every time, or is there some mechanism in C# (compiler or runtime) that optimizes this ?

I've heard of "[String interning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx)", but i am not sure if it's performed for scenarios such as this one, or only when string constants are involved.

Comment: You could always... read the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/0310a1e18c3322b0f1e582583f6597094e6da1cb/src/mscorlib/src/System/Boolean.cs).

Comment: see. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5920209/7990423

Comment: We run in an environment that generates a lot of garbage, and uses an older runtime (Mono). i'm trying to understand if such code is responsible for generating garbage or not.

Comment: Rather than guessing at causes then, shouldn't you find an appropriate *profiler* and *find out what's causing the garbage*?

Comment: We use the Unity game engine (which uses Mono). I am not sure i can 100% trust the profiler output i see there, hence my question on SO.

Comment: Yes, we are calling that many times and i'd like to optimize it (if it generates GC). According to the answer by @Sinatr it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can see for yourself in [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,871f2a3701fb2564), the `ToString()` method is returning value of `readonly static` fields.